# HttpPost call from AngularJS throwing 500-Internal Server Error

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm developing a application where I need to add an user to database thus require POST operation. 
However everytime I run the application I get 500-Internal Server Error for the POST api call.

The following is my code snippet.

```
angular.module('app')
            .constant('userApiRoot', 'http://localhost:82/api/User/');
```

Service.js

```
app.factory('userService', [
        'userApiRoot', '$http', '$q', function (apiRoot, $http, $q) {
            'use strict';
            return {

                apiRoot: apiRoot,
                addUser: function (userData) {
                    var def = $q.defer();

                    $http.post(apiRoot + "Add", JSON.stringify(userData))
                        .then(function (response) {
                            def.resolve(response.d`enter code here`ata);
                        }, def.reject);

                    return def.promise;
                }
            };
        }
]);
```

Controller.js

```
app.controller('BlogInfoController', ['userService', '$scope', BlogInfoController]);

function BlogInfoController(userService, $scope) {
    'use strict';
    $scope.user = {};

    userService.addUser($scope.user).then(function (data) {
        var userData = data;
    });
}
```

HTML

```html
<div class="comments-form">
                        <h3 class="title-normal">Leave A Comment</h3>
                        <form role="form" ng-submit="addUser()">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" ng-model="user.Name" type="text" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Mail" ng-model="user.Email" type="email" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Your Website" type="text" ng-model="user.Website" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="text-right">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Post Comment</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

The error I'm getting is in the attached screenshot.[image: Internal Server Error]

I've tried finding a solution but nothing helps. I get the same error across all browsers.

**NOTE - The same api call works perfectly when called using external client like postman.**

TIA.

Comment: if there is a 500 response, there is a bad conection, better put network console of chrome

Comment: do not convert the post parameters to string

Comment: After removing the stringify I'm getting this error:

TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value) is not a constructor
    at BlogInfoController.js:38

Comment: show your C# code

Comment: postman can work. but from c# with angularjs request is going correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all for their fine solutions to help me out. Finally I found solution to this problem by myself. It might will help somebody someday.

1. Removed the JSON.stringify while passing data to angular service function.
2. Although I've added ng-submit="addUser()" to my form there was no respective function available in my controller. It was the service call in my controller

   userService.addUser($scope.user).then(function (data) {
           var userData = data;
       });

Changed it to the following

```
$scope.addUser = function () {
userService.addUser($scope.user).then(function (data) {
            var userData = data;
        });
}
```

These looks small misses upon finding it but it can stuck you for a while if not monitored closely.

Thanks everybody for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
    var config = {headers : {
            "Content-Type": "application/json; charset = utf-8;"
        }
    };
```

and pass it to

$http.post(apiRoot + "Add", JSON.stringify(userData), config)

because you are using JSON data for post method and doesn't provide any header. Your postman have already included this header.

Answer (score 0):

Instad of stringifying the post data, try to send it as raw data. Like this:

```
$http.post(apiRoot + "Add", userData)
     .then(function (response) {
            def.resolve(response.d`enter code here`ata);
     });
```

Comment: TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value) is not a constructor
    at BlogInfoController.js:38

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try so send the data as an object

```
...
$http.post(apiRoot + "Add", userData)
...
```

and why dont you return the http promise directly?

```
addUser: function (userData) {                    
                return $http.post(apiRoot + "Add", JSON.stringify(userData))
            }
```

Comment: After the change suggested by you.

TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value) is not a constructor
    at BlogInfoController.js:38

Comment: You probably have a syntax error. Can you show the lines in BlogInfoController.js pls

Comment: Whatever I've written is in the post, nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Everything is correct but API is return 500.. Check API is correct. Debug in C# side.

https://www.lifewire.com/500-internal-server-error-explained-2622938

Comment: There is a note at end of the original post, please check that.

Comment: try like this...  var api = apiRoot + "Add"; var sendData = JSON.stringify(userData); $http.post(api, sendData);